# “Because then” in German

Tags: english-to-german, conjunction

In an exercise, I was asked to rephrase the following sentence with *weil*:

> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, denn wir können die Preise vergleichen.

The correct answer is, if I understood correctly

> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, weil wir die Preise vergleichen können.

In English, this sentence would be

> We prefer buying airplane tickets online, because **then** we can compare prices.

Note the presence of *then*, which is meaningful. The *then* implies some sort of causal relation between the first part (buying tickets online), and the second part (being able to compare prices, which is harder when you buy offline). The sentence without *then* might be technically correct but seems weird to me, and the same goes for the equivalent sentence in Dutch. There seems to be no element in the German sentence which plays the role of this *then* (I asked my German teacher about this, but I don’t think I got the question across properly.)

Other examples

- > I had to leave early, because then I would have sufficient time to switch trains in Hamburg.
- > We had to launch the satellite in August, because then we could make use of a gravity assist.

There is a logical relation here, indicated by the *then*: if I had not left early, I would not have had enough time to switch trains. If we had not launched in August, we would not have been able to make use of a gravity assist. *Because then* is very similar to *in order to*.

Contrast with:

- > I often eat bananas, because I like their taste.
- > I had to go to bed early because I was tired.

There is no *then* here, and no second-part-requires-first-part relation. I can like the taste of bananas whether or not I often eat them.

So, long story short: how does one say *because then* in German? And is there a way of saying it that distinguishes *because then* from *because*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The German translation of *because then* is actually pretty simple: *weil… dann* (or less common: *denn dann*).

You can rephrase the first sentence like this to make the causal relationship more apparent:

> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, weil wir **dann** die Preise vergleichen können.

or

> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, denn **dann** können wir die Preise vergleichen.

(in the second sentence I also added the second *wir* which you forgot in your example)

Using *so* instead of *dann* is also a possibility, but then you have put it after the pronoun.

The *dann* in this sentence can also be replaced with *dort* when you're talking about a place (usually a real physical location, but the Internet as a place works as well):

> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, weil wir **dort** die Preise vergleichen können.
>
> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, denn **dort** können wir die Preise vergleichen.

The meaning is probably not exactly the same, but it also puts stress on causality.

I am not exactly sure, though, to what extent using *dann* is considered colloquial. From the sound, I would actually prefer *dort* in this specific case. Phrasing the sentence without either *dann* or *dort*, however, sounds as strange as the English equivalent without *then* as there is no real connection between the main and the sub clause.

Comment: In your sentence why you prefer [...]denn dann können wir[...]? I think 'denn' doesn't break word order. Would '...denn wir können dann die Preise...' be wrong?

Comment: I don't know. *denn dann können wir* sounds better to me. *denn wir können dann* isn't necessarily wrong, but from the sound I would prefer the first one. Had to look that up in a grammar dictionary, though. Generally, I would read the second sentence with more stress on *dann* in the sense of *dann und sonst nicht*.

Comment: _da_ is another alternative to _weil_ and one could use a “Finalsatz” instead of a “Kausalsatz” to emphasize it’s a goal and not just a cause, e.g. _… **damit** wir die Preise vergleichen können_ (also _… **sodass** …_) or _… **um** die Preise vergleichen **zu** können_.

Comment: I disagree with preferring *dort*. *Dort* only implies the place (the internet), while *dann* can also emphasise *wenn wir dort kaufen, dann …* So I would prefer *dann* in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can say: 
"Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, weil wir **so** die Preise vergleichen können."

The "so" creates your causal relation.

Also possible: 
"Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, weil wir **dort** die Preise vergleichen können."

Comment: Made the edit to my answer already. Not sure why, but while proofreading I skipped the already existing *wir* and added another one. After proofreading again I noticed that now there was one too many. :-)

Comment: Oder: "weil wir dann die Preise vergleichen können." Übrigens enden Sätze im Deutschen immer mit einem Satzzeichen und beginnen groß.

Answer (score 1):

*Because then* is, as you assumed, translated by *weil … dann …* or *… denn dann …*; *Dann* can be replaced by *so, dadurch* and others. In fact, the original sentences seem wrong to me. I understand them to mean:

> We prefer to buy plane tickets on the internet because regardless of where we buy, we are able to compare prices.

(It is hard to bring the meaning I perceive across properly. It’s an independent *because we are physically able to compare prices.* The first sentence could just as well be *We often save money when buying plane tickets.*)

If I were teaching German and received either of those as translations, I would mark them as wrong and note the position of the missing *dann*:

> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, denn **dann** können wir die Preise verlgeichen.
>
> Flugtickets kaufen wir am liebsten im Internet, weil wir **dann** die Preise vergleichen können.

This also holds true for your other examples:

- > Ich bin früher abgefahren, denn so (or: dann, dadurch, etc.) habe ich genug Zeit zum Umsteigen in Hamburg.
- > Wir haben den Satelliten im August in den Umlauf geschickt, denn dadurch (or: so, dann, etc.) konnten wir die Gravitation zu unserem Vorteil nutzen.

And note its absence in simple *because* sentences:

- > Ich esse ungern Bananen, weil ich ihren Geschmack nicht mag.
- > Ich bin früh ins Bett gegangen, weil ich müde war.